# iPhone data transfer rate is very slow

Tags: 13.04, iphone

I'm using a Sony Vaio with 8GB of RAM with a Core i5 3rd generation processor.

Recently, I've dual-booted Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.04.

The question is: when I'm syncing my iPhone 4S with Windows, I get nearly 20-25 MB/s data transfer rates, but in Ubuntu I'm only getting 5-7 MB/s of data transfer rate.

Please can anyone explain the correct reason for this?

Comment: Because you are not using iTunes. You are using reversed engineered drivers. When you say synce'd what are you sync'ing? Songs? Is the iPhone jailboken?

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't like Apple because they're all about closed source software while Linux all about open source.  If you dual boot 2 operating systems, that might slow the transfer rate.  Try just running Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just be grateful it works at all:-)  Indeed, the fact that it can "mount" in Ubuntu is a feat.  It uses a variety of programs and files to communicate with the device and obviously, iTunes has "native" support built in.  Last I knew, Ubuntu mounts the entire file system, so just be careful not to delete content.  I have not plugged my iPhone into Ubuntu for some time so I am not sure what the mount point looks like anymore.